# Can remote connections to MySQL be secured?

Tags: c++, mysql

I've written a program in C++ which stores data to a local MySQL database every 5 seconds.
Now I need to store the data on webhosted MySQL database which is remote (the webhosting provides remote access). I think it will be easy to rewrite the program to connect to remote server, but I have a different problem.

Can I make the connection secure (encrypted)? I'm afraid that the password can be sniffed. Must the server support anything special to make it possible?

I thought of allowing remote connections to the database from only one specific IP address (my public static IP), which will prevent anybody else from connecting to the database (unless they hack into my WiFi and sniff my password). So I wouldn't have to worry if someone sniffed my password?

What solution would you recommend to me?

Comment: I cannot say anything about this beyond what I found when googleing "encrypt mysql connection". Then again, I'm too lazy to read through the docs I found in this way and summarize them here as answer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this kind of problem is to use ssh to tunnel to the remote host.
I don't have a specific formula, but a SSH client such as putty can be set up to listen
on a local port and connect to a remote port which is local to the other end of the 
connection.

You would log in to your remote host with ssh, then open your mysql connection to
a local port, which would have the effect of opening a local connection on the
other end of the ssh conneciton.